# BigInteger in SQLAlchemy or not?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, biginteger

I apologize in advance if this is poorly formatted; it's rather late for me.

Basically, I'm using Python with SQLAlchemy. I'm trying to map a class to a PostgreSQL DB table using the [Object Relational Mapper, declarative style](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/declarative.html#synopsis).

According to [SQLAlchemy's documentation on data types](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/types.html#generic-types), I should be able to use the type `BigInteger` to represent potentially large integers in the Database, particularly since I know that [PostgreSQL supports the BIGINT data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-INT).

So, I attempt to declare my class like so:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, BigInteger, Text, Sequence, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'
    __metadata__ = Base.metadata

    id = Column(BigInteger, Sequence('id_seq'), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(Text(32), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, email):
        self.email = email
```

However, when I try to use this file at all, I'm greeted with the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqltest02.py", line 9, in <module>
     from account import Account
  File "/home/pdusen/prog/account.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import Column, BigInteger, Text, Sequence, Boolean
ImportError: cannot import name BigInteger
```

So, according to SQLAlchemy's documentation, the `BigInteger` type exists, but according to python it does not. Is there something here I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for all answers.

Comment: Most probably you're using an older version of SQLAlchemy which doesn't support `BigInteger` but reading the docs for a newer one.

Comment: And you're right. Of course it would be something that simple. Of course, now I'm having a whole separate problem (string encoding... ugh). Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been supported at least since SQL Alchemy 0.6.  As noted in the comments the actual problem was a version that was too old.

Comment: I guess technically I should accept this as the answer, although I'm not proud of this topic being brought back from the dead...

Comment: (Just wanting to make sure that old questions get answers that others can reference later if it comes up again.  I am up to questions that are only a year old now.)